# What is the point of chgrp?

Tags: chown

I know what `chgrp` and `chown` do.
My question is since `chown` does the same thing as `chgrp` (and even more), what is the point of `chgrp`?

Comment: Unix philosophy: One tool to do one thing. Make a simple and work. Not complex.

Comment: Historically, the `chown` command accepted _only_ a new owner, or maybe owner[:group]. You couldn't say just `chown :groupname`, so the `chgrp` command was necessary.

Comment: `chown :groupname` works fine for me.

Answer (score 14):

When you use `chgrp` you are using a simple tool to change one thing... group permissions. For many people this is preferred over using `chown`, especially when you run the risk of mistyping a character while using the `chown` command and completely breaking permissions to whatever files/folder you specified.

So instead of doing one of the following:

```
chown user:group [file/dir]
chown :group [file/dir]
```

You just do:

```
chgrp group [file/dir]
```

This keeps the risks of changing file permissions in a production grade environment down. Which is always good for SysAdmins.

Answer (score 2):

Remember:

- A file is owned by exactly one group and one user. That file may have varying permissions depending on the user and/or group attempting to use it.
- `chown` changes ownership of files to specified user/group
- `chmod` changes permissions of files to specified user/group
- `chgrp` changes ownership of files to specified group